# Fake Call Implementation using phonegap

Tags: android, iphone, cordova

I'm working on an app which has a Fake Call feature. It does not need to be an actual call. It will be just a screen that looks like it is calling, with a ringtone and display. Once the user touches the screen it should not have any functionality.

Can anyone suggest if it is possible using phonegap? If yes, what will be the steps of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Yes. Will Apple allow an app that simulates a feature but is not the actual feature on the app store? absolutely not. Sounds like you are trying to do some less than legit stuff...